# How to play video in QT 4.6 embedded linux?

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I am using QT 4.6 and i want to play video file in QT 4.6 embedded linux ?
Is there any link available or sample code that will help us to develope my sample appication ?

Thanks,
Neel

Answer (score 0):

If your target platform supports it, you can use [Phonon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6.2/phonon-overview.html). I believe there's an example in the Qt distribution but I'm not sure. But it's not difficult to get it working just reading the documentation.

Comment: I want to play video first X86 linux machine then i will take the same code on target board. Is there any sample application with phonon that will play video file ? please give me link that will help me a lot.

Comment: demos/qmediaplayer, in the Qt source tree, uses Phonon and can play videos (assuming the necessary support is present in the Phonon backend for your platform)